# Generate a flat list of all excel cell formulas

Tags: c#, excel, vba

I have a massive program written with VBA and cell formulas. I am tasked to reverse engineer it into C# winforms. I figured for a start, I need to see all the cell formulas in a flat list.

Any existing way to do it? Thanks in advance!

**EDIT: Just to share, with the help of answerers, I managed to come up with this:**

[image: Excel formula browser lets you view precedents in a tree view.]

Comment: You might find the Trace Precedents and Trace Dependents tools to be useful. They're on the Tools > Formula Auditing menu in Excel 2003. For later versions of Excel see http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/display-the-relationships-between-formulas-and-cells-HP010066253.aspx Looking at a flat list of formulas could prove frustrating if much use has been made of `INDIRECT` which can dynamically change what a formula refers to - see http://www.cpearson.com/excel/indirect.htm

Comment: Thanks, but it was because the trace features were not good enough that's why i needed a flat list. I think at looking at a piece of paper is faster in this case. It would be better if there was a "Go to definition" like in MSVS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in VBA (easily modifiable to vbscript) you could quickly dump all formulae in all sheets to a flat txt file (change your path to suit) with an efficient variant array. [code sourced from my article here](http://www.experts-exchange.com/Software/Office_Productivity/Office_Suites/MS_Office/Excel/A_3509-Creating-and-Writing-to-a-CSV-File-Using-Excel-VBA.html%5BCSV%20code%20sample%20here%5D)

```
Const sFilePath = "C:\test\myfile.txt"    

Sub CreateTxt_Output()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim rng1 As Range
    Dim X
    Dim lRow As Long
    Dim lCol As Long
    Dim strTmp As String
    Dim lFnum As Long

    lFnum = FreeFile
    Open sFilePath For Output As lFnum

    For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    Print #lFnum, "*****" & ws.Name & "*****"
        'test that sheet has been used
        Set rng1 = ws.UsedRange
        If Not rng1 Is Nothing Then
            'only multi-cell ranges can be written to a 2D array
            If rng1.Cells.Count > 1 Then
                X = ws.UsedRange.Formula
                For lRow = 1 To UBound(X, 1)
                    For lCol = 1 To UBound(X, 2)
                        'write each line to txt file
                        Print #lFnum, X(lRow, lCol)
                    Next lCol
                Next lRow
            Else
                Print #lFnum, rng1.Formula
            End If
        End If
    Next ws

    Close lFnum
    MsgBox "Done!", vbOKOnly
End Sub
```

**[Updated section - you can isolate formulae quickly in VBA by using SpecialCells. Error Handling is needed in case there are no formulae on a sheet, see GetFormula below**

```
Sub GetFormula()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim rng1 As Range
    Dim rng2 As Range
    For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets
    Set rng1 = Nothing
        On Error Resume Next
        Set rng1 = ws.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas)
        On Error GoTo 0
        If Not rng1 Is Nothing Then
            For Each rng2 In rng1.Areas
            'dump cells here
            Next rng2
        End If
    Next ws
End Sub
```

Comment: It seems that ws.UsedRange.Formula returns an object[,] (working in C#) which consists of all the string in a minimal Range containing all formulae in that sheet. all the string, including non formulae. this set is too big for my program.

Comment: But still some of the objects you used were helpful for my reference. thanks.

Comment: Jake, I have updated my code at bottom with a new snippet that shows how to isolate formulae cells quickly rather than run the HasFormula test.

Comment: Wow! the specialcells trick is extremely fast! Feel like I just wasted another 5 hours last night =(. Now to the next step: compiling decendands and precendants into one string. Thank you!

Comment: Cell dependents & precedents are tricky - it is easy to retrieve related cells that exist in the same sheet via the Cell object. But Excel is not always great in 3D, so off-sheet dependents & precedents are normally found with the exotic NavigateArrows approach [example here](http://www.vbaexpress.com/forum/showthread.php?t=19348&page=2&highlight=navigate)

Comment: +1 for NavigateArrows. learnt another new thing. excel VBA is really not so friendly, isn't it. troublesome stuff.

Comment: In some spaces it is decidely unfriendly, this being a key one. I've done a fair bit of work in automating auditing models (see my profile for my Mappit! addin) and it can be messy at times!

Answer (score 1):

Here is some code that I used to get a list of cells on a worksheet with formulas in them.  It seems pretty fast.

```
try
{
    Excel.Worksheet excelWorksheet = workbook.ActiveSheet as Excel.Worksheet;
    Excel.Range formulaCell = excelWorksheet.Cells.SpecialCells(
        Excel.XlCellType.xlCellTypeFormulas, Type.Missing);

    Excel.Range cell;
    foreach (var fc in formulaCell)
    {
        cell = fc as Excel.Range;
        string s1 = cell.Formula as string;
        int c = cell.Column;
        int r = cell.Row;

        // Gives formula text and location of formula.
    }
}
catch (Exception)
{
    ; // Throws an exception if there are no results.
      // Probably should ignore that exception only
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The key combination ctrl+` (back tick) toggles between viewing values and formulas, it is not a flat list, but it is useful.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Unfortunately it is still too messy for me.

Answer (score 0):

With help from brettdj, I managed to whip up a quad tree search at the moment

```
private static void FindFormula(Excel excel, TextWriter writer, int rowstart, int rowend, int colstart, int colend)
{
    // Select the range
    excel.Range(rowstart, rowend, colstart, colend);

    // Check whether this range has formulas
    if (!excel.RangeHasFormula())
        return;

    // Check if we only have a single cell
    if (excel.RangeCellCount() == 1)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(excel.CellFormula(rowstart, colstart));
        return;
    }

    int r1, r2, r3, r4;
    int c1, c2, c3, c4;

    r1 = rowstart;
    r2 = rowstart + (rowend - rowstart + 1) / 2 - 1;
    r3 = r2 + 1;
    r4 = rowend;

    if (colstart == colend)
    {
        c1 = c2 = c3 = c4 = colstart;

        FindFormula(excel, writer, r1, r2, c1, c2);
        FindFormula(excel, writer, r3, r4, c1, c2);
    }
    else
    {
        c1 = colstart;
        c2 = colstart + (colend - colstart + 1) / 2 - 1;
        c3 = c2 + 1;
        c4 = colend;

        FindFormula(excel, writer, r1, r2, c1, c2);
        FindFormula(excel, writer, r1, r2, c3, c4);
        FindFormula(excel, writer, r3, r4, c1, c2);
        FindFormula(excel, writer, r3, r4, c3, c4);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found this answer, and tried to use the C# code by @Jake, but discovered it was slow.

Here is a faster (and complete) version:

```
using System;
using System.Text;
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;

namespace ExportExcelFormulas
{
    static class ExcelAccess
    {
        public static void ExportFormulasSimple(string filePath)
        {
            var app = new Application();
            var workbook = app.Workbooks.Open(filePath);
            var sCount = workbook.Sheets.Count;

            var sb = new StringBuilder();

            for (int s = 1; s <= sCount; s++)
            {
                var sheet = workbook.Sheets[s];
                var range = sheet.UsedRange;
                var f = range.Formula;

                var cCount = range.Columns.Count;
                var rCount = range.Rows.Count;

                for (int r = 1; r <= rCount; r++)
                {
                    for (int c = 1; c <= cCount; c++)
                    {
                        var id = ColumnIndexToColumnLetter(c) + "" + r + ": ";
                        var val = f[r, c];

                        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(val))
                        {
                            sb.AppendLine(id + val);
                            Console.WriteLine(id + val);
                        }

                    }
                }

            }

            var text = sb.ToString();
        }

        // Based on https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2013/11/13/convert-excel-column-number-to-name/
        public static string ColumnIndexToColumnLetter(int i)
        {
            var l = "";
            var mod = 0;

            while (i > 0)
            {
                mod = (i - 1) % 26;
                l = (char)(65 + mod) + l;
                i = (int)((i - mod) / 26);
            }

            return l;
        }
    }
}
```