# How to use the Excel argument highlight in C#

Tags: c#, excel, highlight

I use formulas in Excel, and I would like to highlight my arguments the same way Excel does, like this:

[image]

I do not want to change the cell's Borders.LineStyle property, I only want to mark specific cells when opening a form, in order to highlight the user's selection.

I couldn't find any related topic on the internet, is it possible at all?

Comment: For those of us not so familiar with Excel: How do you do those highlights manually?

Comment: When in Excel, let's say you have a cell with "=SUM(A1;A2)" in it, if you double click the cell to edit its content, the arguments will be highlighted like in the picture.

Comment: Thanks, I understand. Good question!

Comment: I'd have to dig into the idea myself, but since Excel allows you view a formula's precedents (which is what you;'re looking for), it may be possible to leverage that functionality to get to the precedent cells.  Take a look at these two threads and see if they are any help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7647478/generate-a-flat-list-of-all-excel-cell-formulas   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46025869/excel-vba-code-to-trace-precedents-of-cell  I know that they are mostly VBA, but they may help to point you in the right direction.

Comment: @FrankBall thanks for your answer. I have looked into the links you provided, however I'm not exactly sure why the precedents are what I need. Ideally, I'd like to reproduce the border highlight you can see in the picture, for any cell or range of cells. I can retrieve them, I have everything I need for that. All I need now is to be able to highlight them without having to modify their Borders property.